# How can I write a function that returns the results of a one-line `node` script?

Tags: bash, command-line, node.js

I'm trying to write a very simple `bash` function that uses a one-line `node` script to read the value of a key from a JSON file. Here's the current contents of `utils.bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

project_name() {
    echo $(node -e "require('../package.json').name;")
}
```

Yes, I know there are tools around that allow me to access JSON data more directly, but all of the dev team already has `node`, so it's an existing dependency rather than a new one.

I've made the file executable, but when I `source scripts/utils.bash` and then attempt to reference the function (from the command line) as so:

```
PROJECT_NAME=project_name
```

the output is simply the line I typed. When I try to execute simply `project_name`, I get a `node` error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../package.json'
```

The `utils.bash` script is in the project's `scripts` folder, and the `package.json` file is in the parent folder. I'm executing this from the parent folder (although I'd prefer it not matter). I've tried importing `'./package.json'`, but that also gives me an error.

The end result I want is to be able to reference the value of the `name` key in `project.json` through multiple `bash` scripts.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem with `PROJECT_NAME=project_name` is it should be `PROJECT_NAME="$(project_name)"`. The quotes in that case are not necessary as it's in an assignment to a *scalar* variable, but are a good habit to get into as in many other contexts (including your *`echo $(...)`*), omitting quotes implies splitting the result on `$IFS` characters and perform globbing on the resulting words which you do not want here.

The function has the same working directory as where it's run from, and you said you ran it in the parent of `scripts`. So the function is looking for `./../package.json` not `./scripts/../package.json`.

So you'll likely want to use `./package.json` (not `package.json` as when the path has no `/`, `node` looks in a default search path instead of the current working directory) and figure out why it's giving you an error.

You'll also need `node` to output that value with `console.log()`, and [remove that `echo` with `$(...)` which makes no sense](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2005) (especially  with that `$(...)` unquoted as seen above). So:

```
package_name() {
  node -e "console.log(require('./package.json').name)"
}
```

```
PACKAGE_NAME="$(package_name)" || handle error from node if any
```

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone else who might be wondering, the `echo` in the script needs to be `echo $(node -e "console.log(require('./package.json').name);")`.

Comment: That echo isn't needed at all: https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2005